# Why does osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes return same nodes?

Tags: python, osmnx

In the following code, why does "nearest_nodes" returns same nodes: 1422659162 1422659162 1422659162 ? The previous deprecated "get_nearest_node" was returning different values.

```
origin = (43.8387129,-79.31549783)
dist_1 = (43.8559083,-79.3040332)
dist_2 = (43.8319896,-79.4621784)

bbox = [43.81, 43.87, -79.29, -79.48]
G = osmnx.graph_from_bbox(*bbox, network_type='drive_service')

originId = osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes(G, origin[0], origin[1])
distId1 = osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes(G, dist_1[0], dist_1[1])
distId2 = osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes(G, dist_2[0], dist_2[1])
print(originId,distId1,distId2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> why does "nearest_nodes" returns same nodes

Because you swapped your X and Y arguments' values.